A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed within Microservice solution
I'm working on a microservice solution with 20 + services.
Each service uses Entity Framework & SQL.
I have CrudService that implements standard database operations:
public class CrudService<TEntity> : ICrudService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entity;

    public CrudService(DbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _entity = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() =>
        _entity;

    ....
}

As you can see the DbContext is injected into this service.
I have this registered using the standard DI container that is part of a windows service application.
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("connection");
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddTransient<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(ICrudService<>), typeof(CrudService<>));
services.AddTransient<IResponder, Handler>();

The microservices communicate via RabbitMQ using EasyNetQ.
I have request/response handlers that use the ICrudService, similar to this:
public class Handler : IResponder
{
    private readonly ICrudService<TestEntity> _crudService;

    public Handler(ICrudService<TestEntity> crudService)
    {
        _crudService = crudService;
    }

    public async Task<Response> CreateResponseAsync(Request request)
    {
        var results = await _crudService.GetAll()
                                        .ToListAsync();

        return ...
    }
}

However, when the services are busy I am getting this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on
this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is
usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading
issues with DbContext

I've tried changing the DI registrations to Scoped but no luck
I also tried injecting the IServiceProvider services into my handler to try that but no luck.
e.g.
public Handler(IServiceProvider services) 
{
    _services = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services)); 
}

public async Task<Response> CreateResponseAsync(Request request) 
{
    using var scope = _services.CreateScope();

    var crudService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICrudService<TestEntity>();

    .... 
}

What else can I try? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

You don't show how Handler is registered in DI.

And naming in the code seems a bit off. The constructor for CrudService is called SqlRepository and then you register a SqlCrudService.

Sorted the constructor, sorry.

The handler is also transient

I know you said scoped didn't work but I still think Transient is the issue.
DBContext is not thread safe I would retry setting the lifetime to scoped, and ensure everything else using the crudService also is scoped as well as the DBContext . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

@Nope Thanks for you reply. If I set everything to scoped, I still get the same issue.

And who is using Handler Instances and calls CreateResponseAsync and how is that one registered? We/You need to see the whole chain to understand if or if not every request gets its own handler. I can just speculate that for example that this is at the end of a RabbitMQ queue and you use a setup that takes multiple messages at once from the queue but handles all in parallel and then with the same handler.

If CreateScope do not work for you, then, probably, you have missed await somewhere.

No, everything has an await there

I guess we would need to see full implenetation of a class using CrudService - transient and scoped instace will behave similairly in your scenario. I think it is missing some await somewhere.

I have taken everything out of the Crud Service for now, except the GetAll method which has an await there.
